# Contact Form Function

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I am trying to create a form (through wordpress contact form 7) which when you put details (name and email_ and click a button it take syou through to another form but remembers the details placed on the original form.

An example of this is here http://inchoo.net/get-a-quote/

How is this done and is it possible with the plugin I am using.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://example.com/';"

in additional settings at the bottom of the edit form page would get you to the next page but passing the form values is going to be an issue with contact form 7..

Try to use cforms, i think it does what your looking for